# What causes these errors in my Android Application?

Tags: android, xmlhttprequest

I am getting these errors on my LogCat :

```
02-13 18:52:12.742: E/AndroidRuntime(428): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-13 18:52:12.742: E/AndroidRuntime(428): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.thesis.menubook/com.thesis.menubook.MenuMain}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class fragment
02-13 18:52:12.742: E/AndroidRuntime(428):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1748)
02-13 18:52:12.742: E/AndroidRuntime(428):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1764)
02-13 18:52:12.742: E/AndroidRuntime(428):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:122)
02-13 18:52:12.742: E/AndroidRuntime(428):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1002)
02-13 18:52:12.742: E/AndroidRuntime(428):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-13 18:52:12.742: E/AndroidRuntime(428):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
02-13 18:52:12.742: E/AndroidRuntime(428):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4025)
02-13 18:52:12.742: E/AndroidRuntime(428):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-13 18:52:12.742: E/AndroidRuntime(428):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
02-13 18:52:12.742: E/AndroidRuntime(428):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
02-13 18:52:12.742: E/AndroidRuntime(428):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
02-13 18:52:12.742: E/AndroidRuntime(428):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-13 18:52:12.742: E/AndroidRuntime(428): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class fragment
02-13 18:52:12.742: E/AndroidRuntime(428):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:688)
02-13 18:52:12.742: E/AndroidRuntime(428):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:724)
02-13 18:52:12.742: E/AndroidRuntime(428):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:479)
02-13 18:52:12.742: E/AndroidRuntime(428):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:391)
02-13 18:52:12.742: E/AndroidRuntime(428):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:347)
02-13 18:52:12.742: E/AndroidRuntime(428):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:223)
02-13 18:52:12.742: E/AndroidRuntime(428):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1780)
02-13 18:52:12.742: E/AndroidRuntime(428):  at com.thesis.menubook.MenuMain.onCreate(MenuMain.java:16)
02-13 18:52:12.742: E/AndroidRuntime(428):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1048)
02-13 18:52:12.742: E/AndroidRuntime(428):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1712)
02-13 18:52:12.742: E/AndroidRuntime(428):  ... 11 more
02-13 18:52:12.742: E/AndroidRuntime(428): Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
02-13 18:52:12.742: E/AndroidRuntime(428):  at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1077)
02-13 18:52:12.742: E/AndroidRuntime(428):  at dalvik.system.BlockGuard$WrappedNetworkSystem.connect(BlockGuard.java:368)
02-13 18:52:12.742: E/AndroidRuntime(428):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:208)
02-13 18:52:12.742: E/AndroidRuntime(428):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:431)
02-13 18:52:12.742: E/AndroidRuntime(428):  at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:901)
02-13 18:52:12.742: E/AndroidRuntime(428):  at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:119)
02-13 18:52:12.742: E/AndroidRuntime(428):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:143)
02-13 18:52:12.742: E/AndroidRuntime(428):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
02-13 18:52:12.742: E/AndroidRuntime(428):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
02-13 18:52:12.742: E/AndroidRuntime(428):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
02-13 18:52:12.742: E/AndroidRuntime(428):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
02-13 18:52:12.742: E/AndroidRuntime(428):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
02-13 18:52:12.742: E/AndroidRuntime(428):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
02-13 18:52:12.742: E/AndroidRuntime(428):  at com.thesis.menubook.JSONParser.makeHttpRequest(JSONParser.java:62)
02-13 18:52:12.742: E/AndroidRuntime(428):  at com.thesis.menubook.MenuCategory.onCreate(MenuCategory.java:41)
02-13 18:52:12.742: E/AndroidRuntime(428):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:702)
02-13 18:52:12.742: E/AndroidRuntime(428):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:905)
02-13 18:52:12.742: E/AndroidRuntime(428):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:983)
02-13 18:52:12.742: E/AndroidRuntime(428):  at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4141)
02-13 18:52:12.742: E/AndroidRuntime(428):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:664)
02-13 18:52:12.742: E/AndroidRuntime(428):  ... 20 more
02-13 18:52:13.241: D/dalvikvm(428): GC_CONCURRENT freed 335K, 6% free 7443K/7879K, paused 10ms+10ms
02-13 18:52:23.632: I/Process(428): Sending signal. PID: 428 SIG: 9
```

And I am guessing that this particular line is causing my application to force close :

```
02-13 18:52:12.742: E/AndroidRuntime(428): Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
02-13 18:52:12.742: E/AndroidRuntime(428):  at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1077)
```

Any ideas what is causing this? Here is my java file :

```
package com.thesis.menubook;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.ListFragment;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
public class MenuCategory extends ListFragment {
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> categoryList;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // LOAD CATEGORY ONTO LIST

        Bundle b = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras();
        String table_ID = b.getString("Table");
        String ipaddress = b.getString("IPAddress");

        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        Log.d("IP ADDRESS", ipaddress +" ");

            //CODE FAILS HERE 

        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest("http://"+ipaddress+"/MenuBook/selectCategories.php", "GET", params);

        // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
        Log.d("All Categories: ", json.toString() + " ");

        try {
            // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
            int success = json.getInt("success");

            if (success == 1) {
                // products found
                // Getting Array of Products

                JSONArray category_list = json.getJSONArray("category_list");

                // looping through All Products
                for (int j = 0; j < category_list.length(); j++) {
                    JSONObject c = category_list.getJSONObject(j);

                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    String category = c.getString("category");


                    // creating new HashMap
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    map.put("category", category);
                    int num = 1;
                    Log.d("category #"+num+"", category);
                    num++;
                    // adding HashList to ArrayList
                    if(categoryList.contains(map) != true)
                    {
                        categoryList.add(map);
                    }
                }
            } 
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        ArrayAdapter<ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>>(getActivity().
                getApplicationContext(), R.layout.activity_menu_category);
        arrayAdapter.add(categoryList);
        setListAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    }



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making an HTTP request in your Fragment's `onCreate()`. This is a very bad idea, and is quite rightly causing the system to complain. You have no idea how long the network request will take to complete, and in the meantime the UI thread is blocked waiting for the result.

From [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html):

> Do not block the UI thread

Network activity should happen in a background thread. Have a look at `ASyncTask` or `IntentService`.

Answer (score 3):

Use an ASyncTask to perform network tasks. Since Honeycomb, doing network requests on the UI Thread is forbidden and treated with this exception.